# Boostrap identical validator - pwd & confirm pwd matches upper & lower cases

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, passwords

I have used the below bootstrap identical validator im my page. I have searched and tired for password & confirm password matches uppercases & lowercases also. But i did n't get the expected result. Please help.

```
http://formvalidation.io/validators/identical/
```

Input:

password - sample

confirm password - SamPle

I want that identical validator accepts password match(sample), if input is upper or lowercases.

Below is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="createAccount" class="fv-form fv-form-bootstrap" novalidate="novalidate">              

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                              <label for="password" class="control-label">Password *:</label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-6  has-feedback">
                              <input class="form-control" maxlength="10" name="password" type="password" id="password">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                              <label for="confirPassword" class="control-label">Confirm Password *:</label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-6  has-feedback">
                              <input class="form-control" maxlength="10" name="confirmPassword" type="password">
                              <div id="error-id"></div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                              <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" style="width:100px">Submit</button>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
```

Then in bootstrap validator

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#createAccount')
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-success',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-fail',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            password: {
                row: '.col-sm-6',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Password is required'
                    },
                             identical: {
                                  field: 'confirmPassword',
                                  message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                             }
                }
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                row: '.col-sm-6',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Confirm password is required'
                    },
                             identical: {
                                  field: 'password',
                                  message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                             }                               
                }
            },                
        }
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var password = document.getElementById("password")
, confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword(){
if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
} else {
confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
}
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/diegoleme/pen/surIK)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing both strings to uppercase and then compare them, something like:

```
if (pw1.toUpperCase() === pw2.toUpperCase()) {

 // same values...
}
else {
 // different values...
}
:
```